# Animation of image matrices in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, animation

I have a list of (two dimensional) matrices which I want to combine into an animation. The matrices are integer valued with a specified lower and upper bound (in my case from zero to six). I would now like to build an animation where each of the frames consists of the contents of the matrix.

Now, I have managed to get this working if each frame is merely showing the numeric values via matplotlib's built-in `matplotlib.pyplot.matshow`. Namely, I defined an update function

```
def update_frames(frame):
   animation_image.set_array(matrices[frame])
   return animation_image,
```

where `matrices` contains the list of integer valued matrices I want to animate. Then, I could pass this into the animation module via

```
animation_image = ax.imshow(matrices[0])
ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_frames, frames=len(matrices), blit=True)
```

to obtain the desired result.

I now, however, want to take this a step further by replacing each square on the grid with a specific image, whereas all the images are resized to be of a fixed square shape. For example, at each frame I want to draw a grid of images where the image for each grid cell depends on the integer in the matrix.

Here is a sample animation that I get when using the code snippet above:

[image: Sample Animation]

I do not have finalized versions of the pictures I would like to show up in the grid yet, but I was thinking of textures that resemble these:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Optimally, I would then end up with grids looking like this (aside from the different placement of objects on the grid as compared to the animation above).

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post a working sample of your current animation, and also post your resized images, and a sample grid of images?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, of course. I do not have any finalized pictures but I posted a few examples containing sample textures.

Comment: Building an image composed of small images seems like technical programming. **1.** Prepare a list of 7 small images. **2.** Start with a clean large background. **3.** Implement a method that gets  background, list of small icons and 14x14 matrix. **4.** In the method, use a nested for loops: `y` goes from 0 to 13, and `x` from 0 to 13. Get `p = mat[y,x]`. Get the small image `icon = icons_list[p]`. **5.** Place the icon in the relevant position of the large image - something like: `img[y*10:y*10+10, x*10:y*10+10, :] = icon` . **6.** Execute the method multiple times for creating animation.